# Eclipse marketplace stuck on 'Calculating requirements and dependencies'

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

In eclipse when I choose: install new software... I always have to uncheck the "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" otherwise the whole thing takes forever stuck on the Calculating requirements and dependencies.

I can't find an option for that in the Marketplace which makes the whole marketplace useless, since I get stuck on the same place.

Is there an option somewhere for this, or can I solve it in another way. Or should I switch to IntelliJ IDEA...?

Answer (score 6):

If you install a plugin locally from a zip or jar file, you can simply uncheck the option : 'Contact all update sites during install to find required software'

However, this will not fix the problem completely, and in the Eclipse Marketplace there is no such option to uncheck and you can be hanged at 'Calculating requirements and dependencies' forever.

The true problem are the Available Software Sites provided in Eclipse. Basically, the option above will let Eclipse connect to each of the sites that are enabled and wait till all the sites response. Therefore, even if just 1 site is problematic and not respond, Eclipse will wait forever.

You can configure this by choosing the 'Manage' button next to 'Add' in 'Install new softwares...' or in 'Windows -> Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Software Sites'

It is as simple as testing each of the sites in the list and Disable/Remove any sites that is unable to connect, especially externals sites added by users that may contain typos.

The above solution should work in most situations, but if it doesn't, please check your connection and disable proxy, firewall or allow Eclipse to pass through them.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse Oxygen (jun 2017) and in Available Software Sites, I've updated the location of "Eclipse Orbit Composite" to the last buid repository in http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/

Example:
From: ...download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20150821153341/repository/

To: ...download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/R-builds/R20170516192513/repository

UPDATE:
Change DNS router to DNS google 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4 works for me!

Answer (score -2):

Follow these steps.

1. Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software…. Click Add,
   in the top-right corner.
2. In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter “ADT Plugin” for
   the Name and the following URL for the Location:
   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ Click OK

Note: If you have
trouble acquiring the plugin, try using “http” in the Location URL,
instead of “https” (https is preferred for security reasons)

1. In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to
   Developer Tools and click Next. In the next window, you’ll see a
   list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next. Read and accept the
   license agreements, then click Finish.

Note: If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can’t be established, click OK. When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.

Comment: What does the Android Development Tools have to do with this?